# Find the height of a normal curve to fit a sampling distribution?

Tags: r, normal-distribution, curve-fitting

I am trying to fit a normal curve to a plot of the results of 1000 simulations regarding a difference in proportions. I created a simulation to randomly assign successes and failures to two groups, in order to see the distribution of differences of proportions based on random assignment.  I then want to add a normal curve to the plot of the distribution, to show that it can be approximated by a normal curve. *(Really, I am trying to recreate the plot used [on this applet](http://www.rossmanchance.com/ISIapplets.html): click on Two Proportions in menu, click "Show Shuffle Options" checkbox, enter 1000 for "Number of Shuffles", click "Shuffle" button, and finally click "Overlay normal distribution" checkbox.)* The mean and standard deviation of the normal curve can be calculated easily from common formulas, but the height (scaling factor) of the curve is unknown to me.  Below is the code I created in R:

```
#Assign variables to the data
s1 = 210   #Number of successes in group 1
f1 = 1152  #Number of failures in group 1
s2 = 230   #Number of successes in group 2
f2 = 1106  #Number of failures in group 2

n = s1 + f1 + s2 + f2 #Calculate sample size
n1 = s1 + f1          #Calculate size of group1
n2 = s2 + f2          #Calculate size of group2
dp = s1/n1 - s2/n2    #Calculate difference in proportions

#Put results on cards
cards = c(rep("success",s1+s2),rep("failure",f1+f2))

simulations = 1000  #Number of simulations to run
results = numeric(simulations)  #List to store results of simulations (difference in proportions)

for(i in 1:simulations){  #Do the following for each simulation:

  #Shuffle cards
  cards = sample(cards,n,replace = FALSE)

  #Divide cards into two groups
  group1 = cards[1:n1]
  group2 = cards[(n1+1):n]

  #Determine proportion of success in group1
  p1 = sum(group1 == "success")/n1

  #Determine proportion of success in group2
  p2 = sum(group2 == "success")/n2

  results[i] = p1 - p2

} #End of for loop

#Summary of results:
plot(table(round(results,log(n,10)+1)))
table(round(results,log(n,10)+1))
mean(results)
sd(results)

#Add normal curve to plot
curve(dnorm(x,0,sd(results), add = T, col = "blue")
```

The plot produced is shown below:
[image: Plot of simulation results and normal curve]

It seems to me that the height of the curve does not match the plot.  I'm wondering if I'm missing a scaling factor, and how that can be determined.

Comment: The height of the curve doesn't really matter here, since it's on a different y-axis than the histogram anyway. It might look better visually with a different scale, but I can't think of any numerical application where that y-scale would matter - the area under that curve is 1 by definition, no matter how you stretch the visual scale. Also, interesting use of plot(table(round(X))) to plot a histogram - you could save some typing by simply using hist(X).

Comment: Thanks for your helpful comments. I don't think the y-axis is different - the normal curve does have a height of 28 when the standard deviation is 0.014.  True, the area under the curve is 1. Makes me think I should make a relative frequency histogram. I use the weird plot to maintain/visualize the discrete nature of the results, which is especially helpful for smaller sample sizes.

Comment: "I don't think the y-axis is different" --- you don't think so but you're mistaken. The y axis of the normal density is *density*, while the y-axis of the table is counts. Density is not the same kind of thing as counts. Even if you scaled the counts to proportions, *density is not probability* either. Instead, intervals of density corresponds to probability, if you want the two to look visually similar heightwise (even though their heights represent different things) you need to take careful account of that fact, which requires thinking about the spacing between the values in your variable

Comment: @Drewby To be entirely correct, there should be another scale on the right vertical axis for the density function, since as Glen_b points out, counts and probabilities do not exist on the same scale. You can scale the relative sizes of the count and probability axes as you wish to make them look appropriate, but do keep in mind they are actually separate. Also, I don't quite follow how this version of a histogram helps with small sample size - to me, it's a little less informative, since gaps on the x-axis indicate both a normal bin width, as well as a bin that has no data in it.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying about the y-axis. It seems that while the y-values might be the same, the units are completely different ideas and thus not comparable.  @NuclearWang, I see now that I just need to increase the number of bins for the histogram to make it show what I want.  Thanks for pressing me on that!